# Why does the MaxCellMeasure option in DiscretizeGraphics not work for cylinders?

Tags: graphics3d, regions, mesh

There is an example in the doc of `DiscretizeGraphics`

```
g = Graphics3D[{Cylinder[{{2, 2, 0}, {2, 2, 2}}, 1], 
   Sphere[{3, 3, 1}]}];
Table[DiscretizeGraphics[g, 
  MaxCellMeasure -> {"Area" -> m}], {m, {1, 0.1, 0.01}}]
```

which gives

[image]

we can see the sphere is getting smoother. But the cylinder is not. Why is MaxCellMeasure not effective for cylinders? How to make the cylinder smoother using `DiscretizeGraphics`?

Comment: `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Cylinder[{{2, 2, 0}, {2, 2, 2}}, 1], 
 MaxCellMeasure -> .001]`

Comment: @cvgmt Thank you for reply. It seems that `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion` only works for a single object? What about `g` in my post?

Comment: For example, `Clear[g];
g = RegionUnion[{Cylinder[{{2, 2, 0}, {2, 2, 2}}, 1], 
    Sphere[{3, 3, 1}]}];
Table[DiscretizeRegion[g, 
  MaxCellMeasure -> {"Area" -> m}], {m, {1, 0.1, 0.01}}]`